# how to get old value from the textbox in laravel

Tags: laravel

```
<textarea class="form-control" rows="12" id="body" name="body" {{Request::old('body')}}>
</textarea>
```

In the above code while creating a post and if there are some validation errors the post will reload with the old data submitted by the user but i am getting the blank textarea.

Comment: <textarea class="form-control" rows="12" id="body" name="body" >{{Request::old('body')}}
</textarea>

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Put it in between:

```
<textarea class="form-control" rows="12" id="body" name="body" >{{Request::old('body')}} </textarea>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you can try this :

```
{!! Form::textarea('body',old("description"),['class' => 'form-control','placeholder' => 'body']) !!}
```

**OR**

```
<textarea class="form-control" rows="12" id="body" name="body" >{{Input::old('body')}} </textarea>
```

Hope this work for you !!!

Comment: old('body') without specifying Request, should work to :) It's a helpher function : https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/helpers#method-old

Answer (score 0):

**I has worked like this in laravel 8.**

```
<input type="text" value="{{old('investor')}}" name="investor" class="form-control"  placeholder="Investor Code">
```